# How to fix build error? After upgrade R & RStudio to arm64 pkg with Rcpp won't build: make: "No rule to make target ..."

Tags: r, makefile, rstudio, rcpp, arm64

My first package attempt, using RStudio on an M1 macBook Pro, built, installed and worked; it used Rosetta Stone.

When I learned that versions of R and RStudio could run natively were now available I found I had to uninstall the old versions of R and RStudio and then install the arm64 versions.  The package contains some R methods and 1 Rcpp method. The first thing I had to do was to install the other packages I used.

Builds fails with the error: "make: *** No rule to make target `cpp_saveAsBin', needed by` fireMapperTools.so'."

```
% which R
/opt/homebrew/bin/R
% R --version
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"

RStudio Version: 
RStudio 2022.07.1+554 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (7872775ebddc40635780ca1ed238934c3345c5de, 2022-07-22) for macOS
```

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_5_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.10 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

```
% which cpp
/usr/local/bin/cpp
```

I *think* RStudio & Rcpp uses clang (?)

```
% clang --version
# this produces a lot of text which I skipped
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Dr. Google has not been helpful as most of the URLs returned were created before the arm64 versions were released.

Anything I need to set via Preferences and Options are not clear to me.  "Clean and Build" no longer appears in the Build Tab.

How can this be fixed?

EDIT
I uninstalled both R and RStudio and then installed R from CRAN. Build runs but Install gives the same error.

Comment: This is using `homebrew` per `/opt/homebrew/bin/R`. Please try with the native CRAN R binary.

Comment: @coatless Uninstall R and uninstall RStudio?

Comment: @coatless I uninstalled both R and Rstudio,  installed R from CRAN and installed RStudio.  The error remains.

Comment: Mmm, the R package being installed from source might not support ARM architecture yet. Is there an arm64 compatible version on CRAN?

Comment: @coatless  Yes, that's what I now have installed.  The most recent RStudio is supposed to support ARM but theres no sign of Rcpp in settiung up a new package.

Comment: What is the name of the CRAN package you are trying to install?

Comment: R-4.2.1-arm64.pkg    ... "for Apple silicon Macs (M1 and higher)"

Comment: What is the name of the _R_ package from CRAN you are trying to install from source? I trust you have the right R binary installer from CRAN; but, the R package itself is problematic.

Comment: It appears that RStudio uses Apple's clang, is this true?

Comment: So, everything in the macOS toolchain is built using standard Apple CLI tools (with the exception of fortran). What I'm trying to understand is if the compiled code you are attempting to compile fails due to not being configured for `arm64` but only for `x86_64`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247013/discussion-between-nate-lockwood-and-coatless).